# Rails 3 after_save callback - test if object saved with/without validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

What is the best way to check, in an after_save callback, if the object was saved with or without validations?

Comment: Are you asking whether the object was successfully saved, *regardless* of which validations were run?  Or are you asking whether or not validations were run during the process of saving the object?

Comment: All validation will be ran unless you either specify `on` for the validation or if you pass `validate: false` to the save method.

Comment: I am asking whether the object was saved like that : save(:perform_validation => false) or just save. I want to know which one was it during the after_save callback

Comment: will it be enough to know if the object saved is valid or not?

Comment: No, i need to know how it was saved...